Cannot get final name for export 'decodePacket' of ./node_modules/engine.io-parser/build/esm/index.js
My problem is as follows: when I run a npm run build on my next js application, the import { io } from "socket.io-client"; gives me the error Cannot get final name for export 'decodePacket' of ./node_modules/engine.io-parser/build/esm/index.js
I haven't found any solution, until now it worked, but since a few days it doesn't work anymore, even though I haven't touched anything...
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

export const socket = io(uriServer, {
    transports: ["websocket", "polling"], // Ajoute les transports si nécessaire
});

I've tried a dependency update, I've also deleted all the nodes modules to restart an npm install.
Nothing works.
